# Scrapy: response.body returning gibberish HTML ( ~ 95% of the time). Trying to diagnose

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, proxy, scrapy

## Problem Summary

I am attempting to load this URL (https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/reviews-SRCH_IP2.htm) via a `yield scrapy.Request(url = url, callback = ...)` method call, and the response.body property returns HTML that is not at all reminiscent to the HTML I expect to be returned.

**An excerpt from the body that is returned in response.body**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>\n
<html lang=\'en\' xmlns:fb=\'http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml\' xmlns:og=\'http://opengraph.org/schema/\'\n      class=\'flex\'>
   \n\n<head prefix=\'og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# glassdoor: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/glassdoor#\'><script src="https://browser.sentry-cdn.com/5.2.0/bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script>\n\t\n\tSentry.init(\n\t\t{\n\t\t\tdsn: \'https://a0ab694c43ba4fccafb5987e4a3e8367@sentry.glassdoor.com/8\',\n\t\t\tenvironment: \'prod\',\n\t\t\tsampleRate: 0.0\n\t\t}\n\t);\n\tSentry.configureScope(function(scope){\n\t\tscope.setUser(\n\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\tid: \'0\',\n\t\t\t\tguid: \'0b8f8e55-d91d-4ea7-848a-0a3a1b215fc8\'\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t);\n\t});\n</script><!-- because the getter clears the value --><script>\n\twindow.gdGlobals = window.gdGlobals ||\n\t\t[{\n\t\t\t\'analyticsId\':
```

The full body of the above HTML also does not contain any of the body content I am trying to scrape.

**An excerpt from the HTML body when personally visiting the URL**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' xmlns:fb='http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml'xmlns:og='http://opengraph org/schema/'class='flex'>
   <head prefix='og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# glassdoor: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/glassdoor#'>
      <script src="https://browser.sentry-cdn.com/5.2.0/bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script>
         Sentry.init(
            {
                dsn: 'https://a0ab694c43ba4fccafb5987e4a3e8367@sentry.glassdoor.com/8',
                environment: 'prod',
                sampleRate: 0.0
            }
         );
```

## What I Have Tried

I have another spider (spider1, let's call it) that is calling `scrapy.Request()` successfully and returning the expected HTML. The main difference between spider1 and this spider is that spider1 requires a login to access the information. I have tried requesting the URL above both before and after logging in, but the returned HTML is the same. Additionally, Glassdoor does not require a user login to read the contents for the URL I have linked to above, so I do not believe that is what is causing the issue.

## My Code and What Is Weird

The code to call this is below:

```python
start_urls = ["https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/reviews-SRCH_IP2.htm"]
yield scrapy.Request(url = self.start_urls[0], callback = self.process_page)
```

The weird part is that, when debugging, the HTML actually returns properly (but **very** infrequently – I'd estimate maybe 1/20 times). This occurs without **any code changes**, and I am having significant difficulty in determining what causes this to work in those rare instances.

## My Thoughts

The only slightly valid suspicion I have here is that I need to implement a spider proxy. Glassdoor could be intentionally blocking my requests, explaining why the HTML only correctly returns while debugging – again, this happens roughly 1/20 run-throughs, and it has never returned correctly without breakpoints leading up the `scrapy.Request()` call.

Thank you very much for any advice and/or pointers. It is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is rendered with JavaScript and XHR. So you need  something which can handle this. So use

```
sudo pip3 install scrapy-selenium
```

Get a correct driver for your operating system from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases if using Firefox or another driver if using another browser see https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

spider.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest


class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider"

    start_urls = ["https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/reviews-SRCH_IP2.htm"]

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest(url=self.start_urls[0], callback=self.parse_result)

    def parse_result(self, response):
        for url in response.selector.css('span .url'):
            print(url)
        for title in response.selector.css('.tightAll'):
            print(title)
```

settings.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

BOT_NAME = 'spider'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['spider.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'spider.spiders'


SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'firefox'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = '/usr/local/bin/geckodriver'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS=['-headless']  # '--headless' if using chrome instead of firefox

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True



DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
}
```

Outputs:

```
..
<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::span/descendant-or-self::*/*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' url ')]" data='<span class="url">www.pwc.com</span>'>
<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::span/descendant-or-self::*/*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' url ')]" data='<span class="url">www.primark.com</span>'>
<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::span/descendant-or-self::*/*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' url ')]" data='<span class="url">www.ey.com</span>'>
<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' tightAll ')]" data='<a href="/Overview/Working-at-Tesco-E...'>
<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' tightAll ')]" data='<a href="/Overview/Working-at-J-Sains...'>
<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' tightAll ')]" data='<a href="/Overview/Working-at-NESTA-E...'>
<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::*[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' tightAll ')]" data='<a href="/Overview/Working-at-McDonal...'>
...
```

For further reading see https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed response! I will work on this implementation tonight. I’m fairly familiar with Selenium so that should make it easier. Any advice on using browser dev tools to see how a page is being rendered?

Comment: First thing to check is open the network tab, reload the page and select XHR to see if it is using XMLHttpRequests. If it is see if any of the XHRs fetch a  file with the data you want and if it does see if you can make a call to it's URL using the same request headers if not you would be better with a tool like Selenium

Comment: I am playing around with the Scrapy-Selenium module now. Your for-loop that uses the css selector to print out span URLs works invariably, but for some reason, my xpath selector is behaving the same way as before, where it works like 1/20 times while debugging. Do you have any other ideas? I am going to see if the optional parameters of the SeleniumRequest will solve the issue, but so far I have struck out.

Comment: Could you post your code especially the xpath selector?

Answer (score 2):

Popular sites like Glassdoor most likely implemented crawler restriction, under these circumstances, you will need a proxy hub (IP distributor).

Generally, in the case of invalid response, you want to look out for:

1. Some sites only allow native IPs (or IP of certain Country) to have full access to their business resource.
2. Request frequency.
3. Request headers validation (cookie, user agent).
4. Signed requests (mostly in mobile).

In your case, I can say Glassdoor have rate cap at least. Use this one-liner to test out:

**Linux**

`seq 1000 | xargs -i -P 18 sh -c 'curl -I -H "User-Agent: scrapybot" -s https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/reviews-SRCH_IP2.htm | grep HTTP'`

**Mac**

`seq 1000 | xargs -I {} -P 18 sh -c 'curl -I -H "User-Agent: scrapybot" -s https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/reviews-SRCH_IP2.htm | grep HTTP'`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
```

It's better to have a proxy hub if you are aiming for the full site dump or figure out what the rate policy is and change the delay accordingly. I recommend you to limit your rate and see if these responses occur anymore.

Comment: This worked, thank you very much! I will try and figure out what the rate is, and I will also try to set up a proxy hub. I appreciate your help!